# How do I output a single value from a DoFn and use that as a parameter in another DoFn?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pub/sub with line delimited jsons. Each pub/sub message has an attribute value with the bigquery table name to write to.

How would I get the individual table name value, and pass it to a new pipeline?

Is it ok to create a new PCollection and apply it... from within a DoFn itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a transformation to retrieve the table name within a `DoFn` and pass a `KV` pair of `<tableName, record>` downstream. Then use the dynamic destination support within `BigQueryIO` to route each record to the correct destination. Alternatively, you can also do the retrieval of the table attribute within the `BigQuery.withFormatFunction()`. Below is an example of doing just that.

Here is the overall pipeline structure where JSON messages are consumed from Pub/Sub and then routed to the proper table destination based on a Pub/Sub message attribute. Similarly, you could change the `getTableDestination(..)` logic to retrieve the table name from within the JSON record instead.

You can view this entire example [here](https://github.com/ryanmcdowell/dataflow-bigquery-dynamic-destinations).

```java
  /**
   * Runs the pipeline to completion with the specified options. This method does not wait until the
   * pipeline is finished before returning. Invoke {@code result.waitUntilFinish()} on the result
   * object to block until the pipeline is finished running if blocking programmatic execution is
   * required.
   *
   * @param options The execution options.
   * @return The pipeline result.
   */
  public static PipelineResult run(Options options) {

    // Create the pipeline
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    // Retrieve non-serializable parameters
    String tableNameAttr = options.getTableNameAttr();
    String outputTableProject = options.getOutputTableProject();
    String outputTableDataset = options.getOutputTableDataset();

    // Build & execute pipeline
    pipeline
        .apply(
            "ReadMessages",
            PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromSubscription(options.getSubscription()))
        .apply(
            "WriteToBigQuery",
            BigQueryIO.<PubsubMessage>write()
                .to(
                    input ->
                        getTableDestination(
                            input,
                            tableNameAttr,
                            outputTableProject,
                            outputTableDataset))
                .withFormatFunction(
                    (PubsubMessage msg) -> convertJsonToTableRow(new String(msg.getPayload())))
                .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));

    return pipeline.run();
  }

  /**
   * Retrieves the {@link TableDestination} for the {@link PubsubMessage} by extracting and
   * formatting the value of the {@code tableNameAttr} attribute. If the message is null, a {@link
   * RuntimeException} will be thrown because the message is unable to be routed.
   *
   * @param value The message to extract the table name from.
   * @param tableNameAttr The name of the attribute within the message which contains the table
   *     name.
   * @param outputProject The project which the table resides.
   * @param outputDataset The dataset which the table resides.
   * @return The destination to route the input message to.
   */
  @VisibleForTesting
   static TableDestination getTableDestination(
      ValueInSingleWindow<PubsubMessage> value,
      String tableNameAttr,
      String outputProject,
      String outputDataset) {
    PubsubMessage message = value.getValue();

    TableDestination destination;
    if (message != null) {
      destination =
          new TableDestination(
              String.format(
                  "%s:%s.%s",
                  outputProject, outputDataset, message.getAttributeMap().get(tableNameAttr)),
              null);
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException(
          "Cannot retrieve the dynamic table destination of an null message!");
    }

    return destination;
  }
```